# How to apply multiple regex on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm newbie in JavaScript. I'm trying to create something like stackoverflow's textarea(s) for writing a question-answer. Now I have some regex:

```
text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<i>$1</i>");
text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");
```

Also I have a textarea:

```
<textarea id="Q&A" name="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Now I want to apply those regex on the above `textarea` on click event *(for every pressing key on keyboard)*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `oninput`-Event for this:

```js
function generate(text) {
  text = text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
  text = text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
  text = text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<i>$1</i>");
  text = text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");
  text = text.replace(/`(.*?)`/g, "<code>$1</code>");
  text = text.replace(/>(.*?)(\n|$)+/g, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>");
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Q&A" oninput="generate(this.value)" name="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: `oninput` is an event right? So I think you can use in in JavaScript codes instead of HTML codes.

Comment: Yes, you mean like `ELEMENT.addEventListener("input", myFunc)` or `ELEMENT.oninput = myFunc` ?

Comment: Well, sorry for asking again, But can you please add these two regex to your answer? text between `\`` should replace with  `<code>` tag and `>` should replace with `<blockquote>` tag.

Comment: Can you please write the regex I should add?

Comment: Thanks for your updated ..! however code-method doesn't work as well, but ok, doesn't matter. I will try to fix it